Counting k-ary unlabeled unordered trees with n nodes
I wish to know the asymptotic estimate of counting the trees satisfying the following conditions:

a total of n vertices;
each vertex has at most k outdegree;
all vertices are neither labeled nor ordered, i.e., only the structure of the tree matters.

If there is no closed form for it, I wish I could know the primary part of the reason.
I know there are some similar questions about counting trees; however, this one does not duplicate them:

This frequently asked question counts k-ary labeled tree; however, my question is about unlabeled tree.

This question gave a detailed calculation. However, it did not assert whether the counting has a closed form, which prompted me to take this post.


I appreciate any advice and suggestions.

Can you maybe clarify which question it is exactly that the linked post does not answer? We use the unlabeled multiset operator and an OGF in one variable, representing nodes.

@MarkoRiedel Thank you for your kindness! I have tried to clarify the post. Would you mind retaking a look?
